# Monitoring MySQL/innoDB post-process

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I did `INSERT INTO SELECT` of a huge table (1TB). When the process is finished, MySQL/InnoDB still does post-processing (<strike>creating</strike> *updating* secondary indices, etc.) for hours.

Since these are internal processes, they do not appear in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G`.

I can only check the process by I/O activities.

Is there any way to properly monitor the ongoing processes?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the performance schema?

Comment: @Vérace `performance schema` is disabled by default in MariaDB (not sure about MySQL). Which table does store the pertinent information?

Comment: Disabling the PS is a bit like removing your car's seat belts, the back seats, the passenger seat... to achieve a slight performance gain. You cannot manage what you cannot measure. I would look at (from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-table-reference.html))  - [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/5.6/en/performance-schema-table-io-waits-summary-by-index-usage-table.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-table-wait-summary-tables.html#performance-schema-table-io-waits-summary-by-index-usage-table)...

Comment: Can you show us the `PROCESSLIST` while the `INSERT` is running, then again while it is doing the "post-processing"?  `INSERT` cannot _create_ an index; it can modify existing indexes.  Please provide more details on "creating secondary indices".

Comment: @RickJames my wording was not correct. I have no idea what these post-processes are. My actual question is why I still have heavy `I/O` activities by `MySQL` (as monitored by `iotop`) for hours when the `INSERT` has been finished, and there is no process in `PROCESSLIST` and innoDB buffer is empty in `SHOW ENINGE INNODB STATUS`, though `Log sequence number` and `Modified db pages` constantly change. I will reproduce the process, but there is nothing useful in `PROCESSLIST`. I just assumed, `MySQL` is processing the secondary indices or the table, not creating indices.

Comment: It's probably merging the [change buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-change-buffer.html) into the index pages. That manual page shows some ways to monitor the change buffer size and its progress. The deferred I/O caused by the change buffer merges is normal. You could disable your change buffer before you do the big INSERT, but then your INSERT would take hours.

Comment: @BillKarwin you hit the nail at the head. If you post it as an answer, it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably merging the [change buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-change-buffer.html) into the index pages. That manual page shows some ways to monitor the change buffer size and its progress.

The deferred I/O caused by the change buffer merges is normal.

You could disable your change buffer (see the linked manual page) before you do the big INSERT, but then your INSERT would take hours because all index writes would be write-through.